# How to use the same users table on multiple wordpress sites

Tags: multisite, database, users

I have 3 wordpress sites and I want users to be able to connect to all of them with the same account. The sites are currently in the same domain and everyone has a subdomain.

I was wondering if there is a way to fetch users from a different database or to share a users table with all the sites

Comment: have you considered migrating to a multisite install with each site being a site/blog on the network? This would allow them to share users and sessions. At least 2 of the sites will need to undergo a migration as user IDs will change whether you migrate them into a multisite, or to a single user table. A multisite install is the easiest option available

Comment: Yes I am looking into multisite but I don't see how to share the user table or sync the users between them

Comment: In a multisite you don't, there is only one user table for all sites in a network. A multisite install is a singular WordPress install that contains multiple sites, it isn't multiple folders/installs connected to each other. You would need to convert one site ( preferably the root domain site ), then migrate the other 2 sites into it, abandoning the other 2 installs in the process. It would become much clearer if you set up a local install and activated multisite.

Comment: Think of it this way, you have 3 houses and want to share the same keys. Instead of 3 separate buildings with a super long tunnel between them that has a single front door so you can share the key, use an apartment building instead with a central door. Instead of 3 installs that use 1 user table, have 1 install that has 1 user table, and make it a multisite install

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will try it out

Comment: @TomJNowell It works as you said. All the users from one site exist in the others. The thing is that most of my plugins will conflict with multisite so I will have to use 3 seperate instalations. Is there a way to achive the same thing (with the users)? If so could you point me to the right diraction?

Comment: most plugins work fine with multisite you would need to be more specific about these conflicts

Comment: They are custom plugins and they use realtional tables in the db, I don't know how they will behave. Plugins asside, is there a way to do it?

Comment: it sounds like the code for the custom tables do not use the WP prefix from the `$wpdb` object. If they did then this would not be an issue as each sub-sites prefix has a number to differentiate them from eachother